# Tier price and regular displaying

Tags: price, frontend, tierprice

I have different sizes of shirts, and with it, different prices.

On the grid it shows the "as low as": `R$XX,XX`
but also shows the regular price. How can I remove the regular price?

Here is the website so you can see it: http://nerdcamisetas.net.br/

Comment: Links have a habit of dying off - can you provide a screen shot? @fred

Comment: Here you go, http://imgur.com/6prnMFK

Answer (score 0):

edit the `template/catalog/product/view/price.phtml` file
(most probably in `app/design/frontend/base/default` unless you over-road it)

Comment: but what do I edit ?

Comment: erase the price span from that file